# Override Shortcut Keys on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I am using the `iOS 9.2 Simulator` and I want to attach special functionality with the `(Ctrl + Arrow Keys)` key combinations in my app. Unfortunately, these key combinations have a different meaning on the simulator and they never reach my app. Is there a way to override these? Similarly for `(Alt + Any Other Key)` combinations.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that they have a different meaning in the simulator.  It's that they have a different meaning (by default) in OS X.  They are used for Spaces.  You can disable them in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Mission Control